# Web API not responding for HTTPS

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, https

I created a very basic Web API

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("ClientId", "XYZ");
            return response;
        }
```

- I published the same to IIS and enabled both HTTP (80) and HTTPS(443)
  on my dev machine. I'm testing this using postman.
- Both HTTP and HTTPS work if I test this running Postman from the same
  Dev machine where it is installed. This dev machine is in AWS.
- From my local machine, HTTP works but HTTPS does not. I get the below
  response in Postman

Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://10.XX.XX.XX/api/values.

I'm using the exact same URLs from both Dev machine and local machine.

Any pointers on what else might be missing?

Comment: Please use a tool like openssl to connect HTTPS (Postman might also have detailed log on the handshakes).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't add the client certificate in the postman settings, so you will face this error.

I suggest you could follow below article to add the client certificate in the postman settings and try again.

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates/

Details about how to troubleshoot this error when using postman, you could refer to below article:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/troubleshooting_api_requests/